# Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle - in a loop after iterations

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, pyinstaller, binance

I'm having an issue with my script.

I have a python script that every 5 min query binance to fetch some data. After weeks of working, it starts giving this error:

```
Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle
[('system library', 'fopen', 'No such process'), ('BIO routines', 'BIO_new_file', 'no such file'), ('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'system lib')]
```

I also have multiple instances that go in parallel and they all stop working except for one.

If i try to reboot one script it starts work again while the others keep giving the same error.

Can you help me troubleshoot this?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.